# PHPを学習中なのですが、Notice: Undefined index というエラーが直せません

Tags: php

現在「よくわかるPHPの教科書」にて学習中なのですが、以下のエラーを解除できないためご教授いただければと思います。

```
Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\index.php on line 20
```

データベースに掲示板の投稿内容を登録するという上記教材P.267の内容になるのですが、掲示板に投稿内容を記載し、投稿するというボタンを押すとエラーが表示されてしまう状態です。

https://php1st.com/574
https://qiita.com/wakahara3/items/bb7c8d7a1673b161abe7

上記サイトを参考にし色々試したのですがうまくいかないためご教授いただければ幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

```
<?php
session_start();
require('../dbconnect.a.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['time'] + 3600 > time()) {
    //ログインしている
    $_SESSION['time'] = time();

    $members = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE id=?');
    $members->execute(array($_SESSION['id']));
    $member = $members->fetch();
} else {
    // ログインしてない
    header('Location: login.php'); 
    exit();
}

// 投稿を記録する
if  (!empty($_POST))  {
  if  ($_POST['message']  != '')  {
    $message = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO posts SET member_id=?, message=?, created=NOW()');
    $message->execute(array(
      $member['id'],
      $_POST['message']
  ));

  header('Location: post/index.php');
  exit();

  }
}
?>
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<title> Haratter ：投稿画面</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1 class="font-weight-nomal">一言掲示板</h1>
</header>
<main>
<pre>
<div id="content">
<form action="" method="post">
<dl>
<dt><font size="3"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($member['name'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>さん、メッセージをどうぞ</font></dt>
<dd>
<textarea name="massege" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
</dd>
</dl>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="投稿する" />
</div>
</form>
</main>
```

Comment: エラーメッセージと最初の参照先記事とソースコードの組み合わせで解決できそうです。20行目の`if ($_POST['message'] != '') {`のブロックの前に`if (isset($_POST['message'])) {`を入れて囲めば良いのでは？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。そちら記事に記載があったので試したのですが、“
Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\index.php on line 20” というエラーが表示されてしまいます。

Comment: そうするとこの辺の記事が参考になるかも。[phpのisset()は危険](https://saba.omnioo.com/note/2686/), [PHP 定数の有無を確認したい。](https://chaika.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/06/13/114802), [【PHP】nullの動き方27パターンまとめ](https://qiita.com/kazuki5555/items/5efbca8172a70ac4df4e), [【PHP入門】NULL判定をする方法まとめ！3つの関数の結果を比べる](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/22964) `if (isset($_POST['message'])) {`ではなく`if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {`で試してみるとかでしょうか。[投稿の未入力バリデーションをつける](https://gray-code.com/php/make-the-board-vol7/)

Comment: HTML の方のタグが `textarea name="massege" ` となっていますが、これは `message` ではないでしょうか(スペルミス？)。

Comment: @metropolis さんの指摘の方がそれらしいですね。

Comment: ありがとうございました！確認不足でした、、